# How to update output files without changing them in Snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have changed an initial rule that adds links to database files. Snakemake typically requires all dependent rules to rerun, even the database change is not really relevant. I tried to avoid this behaviour with

```
snakemake --touch
```

Unfortunately it does not work and still wants to rerun all blast processes on top.
How to check the dependence tree ? How to mark individual files as up-to-date ?

snakemake --version 6.4.1

Best, Michael

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided your Snakefile or at least the relevant parts of it.

Comment: The Snakemake file is really long. I would like to present a minimal example but its difficult because I have not figured out the critical part. A way to stop Snakemake incremental build completety and set all files up-to-date would be helpful.